# Pandas timestamp on array

Tags: pandas

Pandas does not convert my array into an array of Timestamps:

```
a = np.array([1457392827660434006, 1457392828660434012,  1457392829660434023,1457474706167386148])
pd.Timestamp(a)
```

gives an an error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-cdf0e494942d> in <module>()
      1 a = np.array([1457392827660434006, 1457392828660434012, 1457392829660434023,1457474706167386148])
----> 2 pd.Timestamp(a)

pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas/tslib.c:8967)()

pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:23508)()

TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp
```

Whereas looping on the array elements works just fine :

```
for i in range(4):
    t = pd.Timestamp(a[i])
    print t
```

gives :

```
2016-03-07 23:20:27.660434006
2016-03-07 23:20:28.660434012
2016-03-07 23:20:29.660434023
2016-03-08 22:05:06.167386148
```

As expected.

Moreover when that array is my first column in a csv file, it does not get parsed to a TimeStamp automatically, even if I specify parse_date correctly.

Any help please?

Comment: try: `df = pd.to_datetime(a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then if you need `array` [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1457392827660434006, 1457392828660434012,  
              1457392829660434023,1457474706167386148])

print pd.to_datetime(a).values

['2016-03-08T00:20:27.660434006+0100' '2016-03-08T00:20:28.660434012+0100'
 '2016-03-08T00:20:29.660434023+0100' '2016-03-08T23:05:06.167386148+0100']

print pd.to_datetime(a, unit='ns').values
['2016-03-08T00:20:27.660434006+0100' '2016-03-08T00:20:28.660434012+0100'
 '2016-03-08T00:20:29.660434023+0100' '2016-03-08T23:05:06.167386148+0100']
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but still does not explain the weird difference between vectorial call to pd.Timestamp versus calling it on each individual item.. And moreover does not explain why the column in the csv file does not get parsed automatically to a Timestamp, when I specify parse_dates

Comment: I think `pd.Timestamp` not convert array to `Timestamp`, if `unit` are `ns`. For converting you can use function `to_datetime`.