# How to create a formatted array from the timestamp column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe called `df_time_series`

[image]

Now I would like to create a formatted array from the pandas dataframe column `timestamp` sucht that this additional array contains only the corresponding hours of the day. This means that e.g for the four columns with timestamp [00:00:00, 00:15:00, 00:30:00, 00:45:00] a 0 should be in this additinal array. For all columns with timestamp [01:00:00, 01:15:00, 01:30:00, 01:45:00] a 1 should be in this additional array and so on.

I tried the following suggestion from here [Pandas timestamp on array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988498/pandas-timestamp-on-array)

```
import pandas as pd

timeDataArray = pd.to_datetime(df_time_series, unit='h').values
```

But this yields an error "ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing". Any suggestions why this error occurs and what to do to create this formatted additional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC get hours from DatetimeIndex by [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html):

```
timeDataArray = pd.to_datetime(df_time_series.index).hour.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['date_col'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

[See Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for details.